# how to add cpp/h file to android NDK CMakeLists.txt ?

Tags: android-ndk

I created new project support C++

I created new class 
     - myClass.h
     - myClass.cpp

And i can't find any way to include this class on the CMakeLists.txt

any help please ..

10x

Answer (score 1):

If you already have CMakeList.txt for your project at correct level then you can just add .cpp filenames to your target.

```
add_library(libraryName SHARED myClass.cpp)
```

You can see [NDK samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt) for more details (adding android libraries etc.)

If you have never written CMake file then lookup appropriate documentation for it.

Comment: [CMake doc][1] might be able to help out. You need to manually add your cpp file into the generated CMakeLists.txt file 


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#existing-project